# PDO password security

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

When using a connection string like `new PDO('mysql:host=' . MYSQL_SERVER . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DB . ';charset=utf8', MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD)`, I imagine that my username and password are sent in clear text to the database server and thus available for all to see.

If this is true, how do I get around it, or, if that info. isn't exposed, how is it sent securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really about PDO at all, it's about the database you use. Not only the password, all other communication will be in cleartext as well, yes. Typically this is not a problem because typically the communication does not cross public networks like the internet, so is hardly susceptible to interception.

If you do need to have that communication go over untrusted networks, you'll want to look into options to encrypt the communication between your database and database clients: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ssl-connections.html

Comment: just what i wanted to know. ill check with my host to see that it is indeed not being sent over a public network. thank you!